# Running a Ruby Script from Rails controller kills the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, daemon

I am trying to run a ruby script from my rails controller.
The script runs successfully when the rails server is started normally as

```
 rails s thin -e development
```

But when rails server is started as a daemon, the ruby script fails to run.

```
 rails s thin -e development -d
```

Inside the controller the ruby script is run with  the **exec** command.

```
 script_exec = exec("ruby /Code/AttendanceReport/attn/bin/scripts/Spreadsheet_proper.rb '#{city}' '#{date1}' '#{date2}'")
```

The above approach kills the rails server and doesn't execute the ruby script. And hence I used

```
 script_exec = %x{ruby /Code/AttendanceReport/attn/bin/scripts/Spreadsheet_proper.rb '#{city}' '#{date1}' '#{date2}' }

      script_exec = system("ruby /Code/AttendanceReport/attn/bin/scripts/Spreadsheet_proper.rb '#{city}' '#{date1}' '#{date2}'")
```

The above **%x** and **system** approaches also fail when run rails server is started with -d. But it does work when the rails server is normally.

Hence I tried a different approach of using **Daemons**
In my controller

```
file_path1 = "/Code/AttendanceReport/attn/bin/scripts/Spreadsheet_proper_control.rb"

script_exec = %x{ruby #{file_path1} start -- #{city} #{date1} #{date2}}
```

The Spreadsheet_proper_control.rb has the

```
 require 'daemons'
 Daemons.run('/Code/AttendanceReport/attn/bin/scripts/Spreadsheet_proper.rb')
```

This approach too fails. Upon logging false value is returned for the above approach.

But when run manually from the terminal, the above Daemon approach is working perfectly.

```
 ruby Spreadsheet_proper_control.rb start -- 'Melbourne' '2015-06-01' '2015-10-01'
```

The ruby script runs while I am logged into a terminal session and started rails server normally – should that terminal session end so would the server.

Concise app environment:-

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Rails version 4.2
- Ruby 2.2.2
- daemons (1.2.3)

The Spreadsheet_proper.rb generates an xls file which is then zipped and sent as response by the controller.

Lines in the ruby code that create and write to the excel sheet.

```
 excel_file = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new     
 sheet1 = excel_file.create_worksheet :name => 'Melbourne Attendance'

 #some code here

 excel_file.write("/Code/AttendanceReport/attn/files/excel/Attendance-#{Time.now}.xls")
```

Since the output of the ruby script is sent by controller as a response, I couldn't go for delayed job.

Is there any other approach to run a Ruby script inside Rails controller successfully without the Rails server getting killed when started as daemon?

Update:-

Upon debugging with rails logger I found that the ruby script is being run by the controller when the rails server is started with -d flag and script being run with **%** and **system**. But the file is not created by the ruby script (i.e. only with rails server started with -d)

The error message after logging in development environment is

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /Code/AttendanceReport/attn/files/excel/Attendance-Melbourne-16:47:24.xls):
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting when "it fails"?  That's important for figuring out why it's failing and what you can do about it. Just trying random alternatives without understanding what the problem is, is not going to get you anywhere, as you've discovered. But we don't really know the problem either without seeing the error message. Look in your Rails app logs.

Comment: Do you really need to spawn it in its own process? Can't you just `require` the thing and then call it *normally*?

Comment: @jrochkind The script is unable to create the xls file. I have updated the question with the logged error message.

Comment: @froderik I am now trying the require approach, but I wasn't aware of this issue since I never tried starting the rails server as background daemon with -d option.

Comment: Okay, now you need to look in the backtrace for the lines that are generating that error. What code line generates it? Why might it be failing saying that file doesn't exist? A file you're writing to isn't normally expected to exist. Is it trying to read that file?  Is it trying to write to a file in a directory that doesn't exist yet, and maybe complaining about that? Could it be a permissions issue, is the 'daemonized' app running as a different user than when you run it under development?  A user that doesn't have permissions to read or write where you want it to?

Comment: And yes, I agree that running a separate ruby script through a shell out is not good design.

Comment: Are you using relative file paths to read or write files, and the Working Directory is different for the daemonized run, making the relative file paths different?  You're just going to have to actually debug this and understand why it's failing, randomly trying different things until it works isn't going to get you there.

Comment: @jrochkind I complete agree with you. Trying different approaches won't work. I am debugging it and at the same time implementing the **require**.

Comment: @jrochkind The thing that bugs me the most is, why the above approach fails only when the rails app is run as a daemon with -d flag but is completely fine otherwise when. Is that something to with the rails server when started as a background job with -d flag not having the require linux permissions to create a file? I have updated the ruby script's code lines that create and write the new xls file.

Comment: "Is that something to with the rails server when started as a background job" I've never used thin before, but that'd be my guess, yep. Let's try to figure it out....  I haven't completely figured it out, it does not seem to be documented very well by thin, but from the following spec in thin source, it looks like there's at least potentially something involving setting the unix user and group and some method called `change_privilege` involved. https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/0770aa00399480bbd8ca7391d416c8700818e719/spec/controllers/controller_spec.rb#L35-L40

Comment: It looks like thin at least has the potential to change the user/group owning the process, and it exersizes that potential when daemonizing. It should be logging the process privilege change when it does, check your logs? https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/0770aa00399480bbd8ca7391d416c8700818e719/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb#L66-L84  Or look at the running process to see what user/group ownership it actually has using a tool like `ps`. I am just guessing and trying to debug here from docs and source, I have no experience with thin whatsoever.

Comment: You also might want to consider Puma or Passenger instead of thin.

Comment: if it is a permission thing you could just set the permissions wide open to test that assumption. `chmod 777 <file_name>`

Comment: Solved this issue by using the **require** approach. Put the class file in libs folder and Rails environmnet auto-loaded it.